# Find max of counts of groups of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I get the maximum value of these groups in a VBA code, instead of a function  as in the image below?

[image: look here]

This is what I've tried:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    c = 2
    r = 3
    lRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
For k = 1 To .Max(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lRow, 1)))
    f = r
    g = 6
    Max = 0
```

Comment: why do you need VBA why not just use a function?

Comment: @Máté Juhász , I need it beacause this VBA code is part of a bigger code and absolutely is necessary for that. Please help me! Thank U.

Comment: please not that this is not a free code writing service where we do others job. Please show what you've tried, describe what you can't do and ask specific question.

Comment: @Máté Juhász I am trying exactly the same question as I asked. why you don't response the specific answer?

Comment: I'm (and majority of other users too) happy to answer questions which demonstrate appropriate level of effort to find the solution themselves and also show respect to the site...

Comment: It is true that if you are using vba, you should be able to show at least what you have tried. It is a simple thing to include at least somehting you have attempted such as    `result = Application.Max(Range("G2:G6"))` being called in your code

Comment: @datatoo First of all should be a code to Countif Range("A"),range("A").End(xlDown) , "group" and then between these counting groups count the MAX and test it in a specific cell.

Comment: @datatoo  Group means Variety of Column A Numbers, in fact it is a serial number for the groups ?

Comment: With Application.WorksheetFunction
        c = 2
        r = 3
        lRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    For k = 1 To .Max(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lRow, 1)))
        f = r
        g = 6
        Max = 0

Comment: I suggest you completely rewrite your question, as your image suggests you only want to derive the value in cell I1 using vba

Comment: Please post the code you have tried in the original post using [edit].

Comment: @Superstar, your example shows raw data, then the counts of the groups, and then the max of the counts.  What is the source material for VBA: the data on the left or the list of group counts?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can try these simple VBA codes to find the Highest Value.*

```
Sub FindMax()

Dim XLastRow As Long
XLastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E" & lLastRow + 1).Formula = "=Max(E1:E" & lLastRow & ")"

End Sub
```

*Or you can try this also.*

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I12").Value = Application.worksheetfunction.Max(Range("E:E"))
```

or

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I12").Value = Application.worksheetfunction.Max(Range("E1:E4"))
```

*I do hope this help you.*

Comment: Nice to hear from you @Superstar,, keep asking :-).